# CosmosDB Graph API / Gremlin API RU calculator

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I would like to compute RU consumed by Gremlin read/write queries on Azure CosmosDB Graph API.

I found an RU calculator https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner for CosmosDB SQL API but not for Graph. In Azure Portal, as well there isn't a way to determine RU consumed by gremlin queries.

Is there any equivalent tool / approach to compute RU consumption?

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: Are you using the C# SDKs for submitting your Gremlin queries or are you using a community Gremlin driver?

Comment: We have a Java based application adn are using community gremlin driver: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tinkerpop/gremlin-driver

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool provided by Microsoft to predict the RU for a given gremlin query or predict the RU required for a graph.

But they provide a detailed view on the current statistics on your graph/DB, in the Metrics tab in the Cosmos Account.

This is customisable per Db/Coll and time-frame.